# MVC HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, encoding, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am attempting to use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode strings that ultimately are used in URLs.

example

/string/http://www.google.com

or

/string/my test string

where http://www.google.com is a parameter passed to a controller.

I have tried UrlEncode but it doesn't seem to work quite right

my route looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "mStringView",
            "mString/{sText}",
            new { controller = "mString", action = "Index", sText = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The problem is the encoded bits are decoded it seems somewhere in the routing.. except things like "+" which replace " " are not decoded..

Understanding my case, where a UrlParameter can be any string, including URL's.. what is the best way to encode them before pushing them into my db, and then handling the decode knowing they will be passed to a controller as a parameter?

thanks!

Comment: What do the encoded URL's look like?  The google example should show `/string/http%3a%2f%2fwww.google.com`

Comment: ok here is the problem /String/rich%27s+tags+test parameter at controller is "rich's tags test" and /Tag/testing+another+tag parameter at controller is "testing+another+tag" so the plus's are not replaced for this string???? i don't get it..

Comment: You might need to do Http.UrlDecode on your controller code before you use the value.

Comment: I could.. but i can see this may cause an issue later. As the expected behavior isn't consistent. I would like to understand why these are being received differently by the controller? Is the route affecting these? And if so why are they different?

Comment: another question.. (thanks for the help btw!) is http://localhost:52871/Tag/http%3a%2f%2fwww.stackoverflow.com returns "HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request". Anyway to get these types of URL's to work?

Comment: To prevent the bad request error message you could turn validate input request off but I think you are going down the rabbit hole. See Sam's answer below for other ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem has come up in other forums and the general recommendation is to not rely on standard url encoding for asp.net mvc.  The advantage is url encoding is not necessarily as user friendly as we want, which is one of the goals of custom routed urls.  For example, this:

```
http://server.com/products/Goods+%26+Services
```

can be friendlier written as

```
http://server.com/products/Good-and-Services
```

So custom url encoding has advantages beyond working around this quirk/bug.  More details and examples here:

http://www.dominicpettifer.co.uk/Blog/34/asp-net-mvc-and-clean-seo-friendly-urls

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the parameter to byte array and use the [HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the "+" doesn't get decoded, use HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode to encode and the decoding will work as desired.

From the [documentation of HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You can encode a URL using with the UrlEncode method or the
>   UrlPathEncode method. However, the methods return different results.
>   The UrlEncode method converts each space character to a plus character
>   (+). The UrlPathEncode method converts each space character into the
>   string "%20", which represents a space in hexadecimal notation. Use
>   the UrlPathEncode method when you encode the path portion of a URL in
>   order to guarantee a consistent decoded URL, regardless of which
>   platform or browser performs the decoding.